# Game Center Integration in Apple Watch

Tags: ios, ios8, game-center, apple-watch

In apple watch application , i want to integrate Game center to show Leaderboard. Is it possible? Because every time i enable Game center in Target's Watch Kit Extension it gives error to install on watch simulator . Also till now there is no official Device Compatibilty written in apple docs for Apple watch as in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeviceInformation/Reference/iOSDeviceCompatibility/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix/DeviceCompatibilityMatrix.html from we can check whether it it compatible or not? Please guide me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Game Center isn't supported in WatchKit at this time.

Comment: As far as i tried i believe that it is not possible yet. But i am still looking for any official link. So can you provide any official link?